# How to make Emacs new comment line starts with '*' for c comments?

Tags: emacs

For the following c comment (`^` is the cursor)

```
/*
 * foo bar^
```

If I push enter with the cursor after `bar`, I get

```
/*
 * foo bar
^
```

But I want to have

```
/*
 * foo bar
 *^
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function which does what you want ['c-context-line-break](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Filling-and-Breaking.html).

You can add the following to your .emacs to get the desired behavior:

```
(eval-after-load "cc-mode"
  '(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "RET") 'c-context-line-break))
```

Now, this will require you to type the * on the second line (where you began with `* foo bar` , but each subsequent <kbd>RET</kbd> will put the * in place automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems combining these two resources could solve your issue:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dLine-Comments.html

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoFillMode

M-j continues the current comment. And per the page:

> When Auto Fill mode is on, going past the fill column while typing a comment also continues the comment, in the same way as an explicit invocation of M-j.

In the second link there are a couple of options. The two most simple being:
`M-x auto-fill-mode`
to enable it just now for this file. Or adding this to your .emacs file:
`(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)`, to have it always activated.

In the link theres examples for making it toggleable, having it ask you on new files and more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually have auto-fill-mode enabled but I still have to use `M-j` to continue the comment... what would I do?

Answer (score 1):

M-j runs the command c-indent-new-comment-line.